# Error: expression 'none(int)' is of type 'Option[system.int]' and has to be discarded

Tags: templates, nim-lang

```
import options

template p[T] = none(T)

discard p[int]
```

> templat.nim(5, 10) Error: expression 'none(int)' is of type
>   'Option[system.int]' and has to be discarded

I think writing `discard` in front of the template instantiation is a reasonable enough way to do what the compiler asks, no ? Now it's just being grumpy.

EDIT: I've tried new things and it may be yet-another-case of very unhelpful compiler messages.

```
import options
template p[T](): untyped = T.none
discard p[int]()
```

This builds. The main change might be the `untyped` return type (note that `typed` didn't work either, with the same weird message).
And last flabbergast, `T.none` was fine but not `none(T)`. I thought from UFCS both should be equivalent.

Comment: This is probably a good candidate for a bug report: https://github.com/nim-lang/Nim/issues

Comment: @dom96 I suspect you refer to the last point, I took your advice, and posted a report here: https://github.com/nim-lang/Nim/issues/7461

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, Nim will assume that the template returns a "statement list" (a block of Nim code, which doesn't denote any value). Since this must be a well-formed block, the return values of all calls inside it must be properly handled or discarded, hence you see the error.

To solve the problem, just add a return value to the template:

```
  import options

  template p[T]: auto = none(T) # notice that I added "auto" here!

  discard p[int]
```

Comment: thanks ! more stuff are starting to make sense with lots of perseverance, but damn, Nim is not gentle, it's like a wild bison you have to tame.

Comment: There were multiple questions in my question, sorry about that, but now I still don't get why `untyped` (and `auto`) works, and `typed` does not. I thought historically, `untyped` was `StatementList` which means stuff like `if` which has no value. But here I return a well typed expression, so historically: `expr`, which means, `typed` today. The compiler asks me to discard the result though.